# Can we upload new iOS build on App Store without using xcode 5.1.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcode5.1

I have read some where that all new app must have build with xcode v5.1.1
Does it mandatory?

Comment: Can you post that link from where you read this?

Comment: I don't think it's mandatory but if you are targeting iOS7.1 and above you should use that Xcode 5.1 and above. Because you can build your app on iOS 7.1 only if you have Xcode 5.1.

Comment: here is the link https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04252014a

Comment: I had also read this statement on upload time of the just 2 days before.

Comment: Well that links answers your own question.